# Map a pandas DataFrame index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe indexed by `datetime`:

```
> df.head()

                        value
2013-01-01 00:00:00 -0.014844
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.243548
2013-01-01 02:00:00  0.463755
2013-01-01 03:00:00  0.695867
2013-01-01 04:00:00  0.845290
(...)
```

if I wanted to plot all values by date, I could do:

```
times = map(lambda x : x.date(), df.index)
values = df.value
plot(values, times)
```

Is there a more "pandas idiomatic" way to do it? I tried the `.rename` method, but I got a assertion error:

```
df.rename(lambda x : x.time())
```

What I really wanted was to do something like a boxplot:

```
df.boxplot(by = lambda x : x.time())
```

but without the standard deviation boxes (which will be substituted by estimated confidence bands). Is there a way to do this with a simple pandas command?

---

I don't know if I was clear about what was the problem. The problem is that I have a datetime field as index of the dataframe, and I need to extract only the time part and plot the values by time. This will give me lots of points with the same x-axis, which is fine, but the `rename` method seems to expect that each value in the resulting index is unique.

Comment: You rename got assertion is because that you cannot have two index with the same value, and tragedy is that all the indexes in your examples are in the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot natively with the DataFrame [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method, for example:

```
df.plot()
df.plot(kind='bar')
...
```

*This method gives you a lot of flexibility (with all the power of matplotlib).

The [visualisation section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) of the docs goes into a lot of detail, and has plenty of examples.*

---

In 0.12+ there's a time method/attribute on an DatetimeIndex (IIRC due to this question):

```
df.index.time  # equivalent to df.index.map(lambda ts: ts.time())
```

To plot only the times, you could use:

```
plot(df.index.time, df.value)
```

However this seems only slightly better than your solution, if at all. Perhaps timeseries index ought to offer a time method, similar to how it does for hour (I vaguely recall a similar question...):

```
plot(df.index.hour, df.value))
```

Comment: but how can I transform the index to extract only the time from the date time?

Comment: Hmmm `plot(df.index.map(lambda ts: ts.time()), df.value)` is slightly better but still seems unsatisfying. Maybe timeseries index should offers a time method (like it does for hour i.e. `plot(df.index.hour, df.value)`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

crate the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from numpy.random import randn
rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = TimeSeries(randn(72), index=rng)
```

plot date-value:

```
ts.to_period("D").plot(style="o")
```

[image]

plot time-value:

```
TimeSeries(ts.values, index=DatetimeIndex(ts.index.values - 
    ts.index.to_period("D").to_timestamp().values)).plot(style="o")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time values, then this is fairly fast.

```
def dt_time(ind):
  return np.array([time(*time_tuple) for time_tuple in zip(ind.hour, ind.minute, ind.second)])
```

Calling `map` will be magnitudes slower.

```
In [29]: %timeit dt_time(dt)
1000 loops, best of 3: 511 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit dt_map(dt)
10 loops, best of 3: 96.3 ms per loop
```

for a 100 length DatetimeIndex.